# Is a generic BehaviorExtensionElement possible?

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, configuration

I have some service behaviors for WCF services that I just want to register; there's no configuration. I figured I could skip creating a BehaviorExtensionElement descendant each time by using generics:

```
public class SimpleBehaviorExtensionElement<TBehavior> : BehaviorExtensionElement
    where TBehavior: new()
{
    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new TBehavior();
    }

    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get { return typeof(TBehavior); }
    }
}
```

And in Web.config:

```
<behaviorExtensions>
  <add name="myBehavior2"
    type="WcfService1.SimpleBehaviorExtensionElement`1[[WcfService1.MyBehavior,
      WcfService1]], WcfService1"/>
</behaviorExtensions>
```

WcfService1.MyBehavior exists, implements IServiceBehavior, and has been tested.

But when I reference <myBehavior2/> in the behavior section of the config file, I get:

> An error occurred creating the
>   configuration section handler for
>   system.serviceModel/behaviors:
>   Extension element 'myBehavior2' cannot
>   be added to this element. Verify that
>   the extension is registered in the
>   extension collection at
>   system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions.
>   Parameter name: element

Everything works if I create a non-generic BehaviorExtensionElement descendant, which I can do. But now it bugs me. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with config files, at least not in a reliable fashion.

The reason is that if you have a generic class `class A<T>` and a class parameter `class B` the framework will not create a the class `A<B>` until you declare a type of `A<B>` by using it. The name in the format A`1[[B, Assm]] is just the name that gets created at run time - it means the generic "A" that takes 1 parameter created with the following types. It is not a cue to a type factory - which is what you need for what you are doing. So you *might* be able to get this to work *if* you are lucky and `A<B>` happens to have been declared, but I would not rely on it.

This is, I believe, fixed in the data contract serialization that is used by later parts of the framework, but config is old. If you look at XAML there is the ability to use a type arguments with a type:

```
<scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
```

Note this is an Explicit instruction to a type factory - something that the config parser does **not** have.

So sadly this leaves you with the expense of declaring a concrete type for each extension - but it is not a lot of work :

```
public class MyBehaviorExtensionElement : 
         SimpleBehaviorExtensionElement<MyBehavior> {}
```

And on the plus side it makes your config file more readable.

```
<behaviorExtensions>
  <add name="myBehavior" 
    type="BehaviorTest.MyBehaviorExtensionElement, ServiceLibrary"/>      
</behaviorExtensions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

I guess the reason the exception is getting thrown is because of way behavior elements are added [WCF extensions without including the assembly version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716399/wcf-extensions-without-including-the-assembly-version).

When specifying the type of the behavior, **Version**, **Culture** and **PublicKeyToken** attributes **MUST** be added as well. Please also note that there **MUST** be exactly one space after each , (comma), and the attributes **MUST** appear in aforementioned order.

So, in your example, following should work:

```
 <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="myBehavior2"
         type="WcfService1.SimpleBehaviorExtensionElement`1[[WcfService1.MyBehavior, WcfService1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], WcfService1" />
</behaviorExtensions>
```

Comment: That's not the case. I have working behavior extension elements that specify the type without a version.

Comment: @TrueWill: I doubt that any of those working elements is actually a generic one.

Comment: have you tried this and successfully gotten it to work with a generic extension?

Comment: @TrueWill: You can bet I did :) I can send you a sample, if you want it.